# how to get contact information to tableviewcell from all contacts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i am trying to reproduce native phone app favorites tab in my app , i am succeed displaying all contacts 
my code

```
-(IBAction)addFavorite { 
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

how can i get full contact information of a contact into tableview cell, like in real app

and how can i get red color delete buttons to edit them ?

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you must use database(coredata or sqlite) and store contacts in the database .

when you want to display fetch all records and make 26 section for a-z alphabet then according to first alphabet categories them.

for delete button,

```
yourTable.editing=YES;
```

this gives red - marks on left in table cell and on tapping these you get red delete button.
and you can write your deletion code in

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
 forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

above method.

use this information with your logics